# PSM Questions for spatial research question

Tags: propensity-scores

I want to evaluate a policy introduced in the UK - a fund that has provided cash to coastal communities to generate jobs and gdp growth. All coastal regions are eligible - as such i know what areas have been treated and not since 2012.

Is Propensity score matching a suitable technique to compare treated regions (coastal) with counterfactual regions (non coastal regions)?

Or am i missing the point of PSM?

Comment: Why would you not compare treated coastal regions that did get the funds with untreated coastal regions that did not and use PMS on that? Of course you could use the non-coastal ones, but it's going to make the matching much harder (making sure you compare apples with apples)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Maarten Punt, try as much as possible to compare apples with apples. I want to stress another point that I believe is very important in your analysis.  It’s about ***spatial autocorrelation***. In fact, a lot of research in geographic economics has shown that growth is spatially autocorrelated. One of the key messages from this literature is that geographical proximity matters for growth.

In this vein, ***the presence of spatial interactions imply that subsidy in a coastal region is likely to affect contiguous regions (even the non-coastal ones)***. Therefore, you need more sophisticated propensity score methods which can take into account neighbourhood effects. The following paper will give you some insights in that direction: https://ideas.repec.org/p/rcr/wpaper/05_15.html